# How to «git log --branches» except some specific branches?

Tags: git, command-line

I want to check my git history graph except for some branch I want to ignore.

I use the following command : `git log --graph --date-order --branches --remotes=origin   --pretty=format:'%C(auto)%h%Creset %C(auto)%d%Creset'`

This returns something like this:

```
* 8dc1a70  (HEAD -> features/feature1)
* 625c057 
* 087b386 
| * b5ebdf8  (features/feature2)
| * 97ccde9 
| * a0397db 
|/  
| * c392c83  (features/feature3)
|/  
* 7fd1bf0  (origin/master, origin/HEAD, master)
* a449e11
* 0d225ee
* 7d84b63
```

Sometimes, the branch `features/feature2` contains lot of commit and I would like to ignore this specific branches.

I tried to add `--branches --not --branches=feature/feature3` but this also exclude`origin/master` and all commit under it (I assume it's because it's an ancestor).

How to check «all git log except some named branches» ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's an `--exclude` option, see [its docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt---excludeltglob-patterngt)

```
git log --no-walk --oneline --exclude=master --branches
```

will list all the branch tips except `master`'s.

Comment: Thanks you ! I think I tried this, but without reading the doc carefully : my mistake was to but `--exclude` after the `--branches` options.